# Cloud function e2e

Tags: go, google-cloud-functions, e2e-testing, endly

How do I write e2e or integration testig for cloud function, so far
I've been able to use bash automation script, but when deployment I can not easily detect it

```
gcloud functions deploy MyFunction --entry-point MyFunction --runtime go111 --trigger-http
```

Answer (score 1):

Bash is a good starting point, how about using some e2e testing tools, for instance
with [endly](https://github.com/viant/endly/) workflow e2e runner your deployment workflow may look like the following

```
pipeline:
  deploy:
    action: exec:run
    comments: deploy HelloWord triggered by http
    target: $target
    sleepTimeMs: 1500
    terminators:
      - Do you want to continue
    errors:
      - ERROR
    env:
      GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS: ${env.HOME}/.secret/${gcSecrets}.json
    commands:
      - cd $appPath
      - export PATH=$PATH:${env.HOME}/google-cloud-sdk/bin/
      - gcloud config set project $projectID
      - ${cmd[4].stdout}:/Do you want to continue/ ? Y
      - gcloud functions deploy HelloWorld --entry-point HelloWorld --runtime go111 --trigger-http
    extract:
      - key: triggerURL
        regExpr: (?sm).+httpsTrigger:[^u]+url:[\s\t]+([^\r\n]+)

  validateTriggerURL:
    action: validator:assert
    actual: ${deploy.Data.triggerURL}
    expected: /HelloWorld/
post:
  triggerURL: ${deploy.Data.triggerURL}
```

you can also achive the same with using cloudfunction service API calls

```
defaults:
  credentials: $gcSecrets
pipeline:
  deploy:
    action: gcp/cloudfunctions:deploy
    '@name': HelloWorld
    entryPoint: HelloWorldFn
    runtime: go111
    source:
      URL: ${appPath}/hello/
```

Finally, you can look into practical serverless e2e testing examples(cloudfunctions, lambda, firebase, firestore, dynamodb,pubsub, sqs,sns,bigquery etc ...)

[serverless_e2e](http://github.com/adrianwit/serverless_e2e)

Comment: Disclaimer: I am author or both endly and serveless_e2e example project